# Running NUnit RemoteTestRunner tests located in console app, not in dll

Tags: c#, nunit

I've successfully been able to run dll tests using NUnits core dll RemoteTestRunner, so that is not the issue. The problem arise when I have to run the tests we have located in a console app with its own app.config that has a ConnectionString key field.  This field is read and initialized by a shared core dll that is used to access the database.

It works great running it in NUnit and also with Testdriven.net from VS. But when I use RemoteTestRunner the ConnectionString never gets initialized. I don't know why, but maybe the config is never read. Is there anyone out there who might know how to accomplish running the .exe tests from c# code?